# Use different methods based on an integer value

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

this is something i cannot get my head around, now i have something like this:

```
boolean method1(int a){
//something
returns true;
}

boolean method2(int a){
//something
returns true;
}

for (int i; i<100; i++){
  switch (someInt){
  case 1: boolean x = method1(i);
  case 2: boolean x = method2(i);
  }


}
```

What i would like is to take the switch out of the loop, as the someInt will stay the same for every i, thus need to be decided only once, but i need x to be checked for every i, so i would need something like:

```
    switch (someInt){
          case 1: method1(); //will be used in loop below
          case 2: method2(); //will be used in loop below
          }

   for (int i; i<100; i++){
       boolean x = method the switch above picked
   }
```

Comment: Look up the strategy pattern. Basically, the code you're trying to write isn't very clean / I don't think it's possible without reflection

Comment: You can use Java 8 method references: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/java-8-method-references-explained-5-minutes/

Comment: the original version is not bad. other solutions are all `switch` in disguise actually, and they perform much worse :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Java 8 method references.

- https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/java-8-method-references-explained-5-minutes/
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Here is an example:

```
public class WithMethodRefs {
    interface MyReference {
        boolean method(int a);
    }

    boolean method1(int a) {
        return true;
    }

    boolean method2(int a) {
        return false;
    }

    public void doIt(int someInt) {
        MyReference p = null;
        switch (someInt) {
        case 1:
            p = this::method1;
            break;
        case 2:
            p = this::method2;
            break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            p.method(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use [`java.util.function.IntConsumer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntConsumer.html) instead of defining your own functional interface.

Comment: This switch statement is broken, there is no break in it

Comment: @DmitryP. Thanks! Added missing `break`s. @MarkRotteveel I defined my own interface for demonstration purposes. The signature of the `methodX` methods may change in future.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace your conditional with polymorphism:

Some examples:

- http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html
- https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism
- http://tmont.com/blargh/2011/11/refactoring-a-switch-statement

An example with your code:

```
    interface CallIt {
        boolean callMe(int a);
    }

    class Method1 implements CallIt {
        public boolean callMe(int a) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    class Method2 implements CallIt {
        public boolean callMe(int a) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    void doIt(int someInt) {
        CallIt callIt = null;
        switch (someInt) {
        case 1:
            callIt = new Method1();
            break;
        case 2:
            callIt = new Method2();
            break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            boolean x = callIt.callMe(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Polymorphism can't be used in some cases, but I would definitely think about this. So +1.

Comment: Although method references is exactly what the OP is asking for, this solution is well worth considering since it uses Object-Oriented design practices.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents. If we started to be functional let's do it till the end!

```
    IntFunction<IntFunction<Boolean>> basic = x -> i -> {
        switch (x) {
            case 1: return method1(i);
            case 2: return method2(i);
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("No method for " + someInt);
        }
    };
    IntFunction<Boolean> f = basic.apply(someInt);
    IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(i -> {
        boolean result = f.apply(i);
        //do something with the result
    });
```

Also I don't see any break statements in your switch. Maybe it's because this is just an example, but check if they are here. You will get method2() for all cases otherwise.